# Error in BorshSerialize/Deserialize when struct pulled from another crate

Tags: rust

I have a struct A in a.rs that I am trying to serialize with Borsh serialization with Rust. A is shown below.

```
use crate::B;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub struct A {
 pub a: i32
 pub b: Vec<B>,
};
```

Here B is in some other file where I express B as follows in some file b.rs within same lib.rs.

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub struct B {
 pub a1: i32
 pub b2: Vec<i32>,
};
```

When I build the crate I get the following error.

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `b::B`
= help: the following other types implement trait `BorshSerialize`:
             &T
             ()
             (T0, T1)
             (T0, T1, T2)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
           and 110 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `BorshSerialize` for `Vec<b::B>`
```

Its very weird because in b.rs , I am already defining the macro #[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)] for B. Will I have to move B above A or is there anything else I am missing out.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile straight away because of the missing commas and extra semicolons, but after fixing that, it works for me. Is `b::B` in a different crate? If so, is that crate using the same version of borsh?

Comment: It’s using the same version of borsh. Even after putting the , it didn’t compile. You can try with putting B in a separate file b.rs and including B in a.rs (where A is defined) through the headers.

Comment: Can you upload your crate exhibiting the issue to Github or something? Or at least include the file tree and the whole files and everything in your question.

Comment: I set it up like you said you did and see no error. Post the full output of `cargo check`.

Comment: You `use crate::B;` in `a.rs`, but if `B` is in `b.rs` then it probably should be `use crate::b::B;`. What does your `main.rs` or `lib.rs` look like?